# How to forbid Eclipse to highlight current method/class in the margin

Tags: eclipse

How do I tell Eclipse (JDT) to stop highlighting current method or class in the margin area to the left of the editor?  For me it is nothing but visual garbage.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such visual garbage in your view is called `range indicator` . It can be disabled in the Text Editors preference page :

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I looked in [General > Editors] and [Java > Editor], but missed the [Text Editors]…

Comment: Welcome , my screen cap is captured from version 3.7 .It also does not have `[Text Editors]`  , instead it has  `[General -->Editors--> Text Editors]`